# How to get previous week start date and time and end date and time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, datetime, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get previous week data ..
Suppose I am in current week whether start or end I have to get value of previous week.
Suppose today is 7 Nov Monday.
But I have to get value of Last Sunday 30 Oct (00:00) to 5th Nov Saturday (23:59:59)
So, start date would be 30 oct and end date would be 5th Nov

And tomorrow will be 8 Nov Tuesday but then also
I have to get value of Last Sunday 30 Oct (00:00) and 5th Nov Saturday (23:59:59)
start date would be 31 oct and end date would be 5th Nov,
and it should be dynamic, if week change then again previous week of current week.

I am using below code but from this I am getting current week start and end weekdays

```
var curr = new Date; // get current date
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();
var last = first + 6;

var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toUTCString();
var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last)).toUTCString();
```

Comment: `toUTCString`  Your asking for the result in UTC, but do you want the locale time.?

Comment: This year october 31 was a **monday**.

Comment: [Maybe helpful](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-m99h9b?file=index.js)

Comment: @KooiInc sorry my bad 30 Oct

Comment: Current date minus the weekday will get you Sunday of the current week. Adding 6 to that will get you Saturday of the current week. If you want *last* week's weekdays, logically, you would *subtract* 6 days from Sunday (to get last Monday), then add 5 days (to get last Friday).

Answer (score 2):

You can move the var first to 7 days before then you will get the previous week's first day and last day.

Try out this code.

```js
var curr = new Date; // get current date
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();
first = first - 7
var firstdayOb = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
var firstday = firstdayOb.toUTCString();

var firstdayTemp = firstdayOb;

   
var lastday = new Date(firstdayTemp.setDate(firstdayTemp.getDate() + 6 )).toUTCString();
console.log(firstday);
console.log(lastday);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have to set start det Sunday and End date Sturday , I have updated the question , I did mistake in my question

Comment: I've edited my code try it.